# Ubuntu 14.04 runs slow on AMD A4 - 4Gb Ram

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, performance

Recently I bought laptop of ASUS with configuration

- AMD Quad Core A4 - 5000 1.5Ghz
- Memory 4Gb
- HDD 500Gb

Even after installing LUbuntu, I didn't see much increase in speed.

Currently installed softwares
- LAMP stack
- Eclipse IDE

Is there anything I am missing out to perform configuration to achieve maximum performance out of a Quad Core Processor

Comment: your hardware should be powerful enough. Do you have the correct graphic card drivers installed? How do you realize that your system is slow?

Comment: Suppose I am editing any file in gedit or Eclipse and I scroll down, the scrolling continues for longer time, suppose I search something in my eclipse again it happens slowly. How can I check for correct drivers??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your system faster, you could try the following:

- Install the proprietary AMD driver, so the APU speed can be regulated.

  Open *Software & Updates*, go to *Additional drivers* and select *fglrx*.
- Install the packages *preload* and *prelink*. These take certain actions to make the system faster.

  Execute `sudo apt-get install prelink preload` in a terminal.
- Reduce Swap usage. The default *swappiness* value is 60, which may be too high.

  Open the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set the swappiness parameter:
  `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` in a terminal.
  New line at the end: `vm.swappiness = 10`, then another linebreak, save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
- Enable boot profiling. The next reboot may take a bit longer, but the following should be faster.

  Open `/etc/default/grub` and append `profile` to the line that says `quiet splash`:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash profile"
  ```

  If you don't want your boot menu to appear (if it even does), set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`

  Save, exit and run `sudo update-grub`.

If you apply these changes, your computer should get faster after a reboot.

Comment: Trying these steps, will let you know the progress, Thanks for sharing the info :)